# Grub recognizing but not booting windows

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot, manjaro, ssd

I'm running Manjaro 20 installed on a M.2 SSD (nvme0n1). And Windows is installed on a separate SSD (sdb).

Booting into Linux from grub works perfectly, but when I want to boot into windows from grub I get the following error:

```
error: no such device: 9287-5622
error: disk `hd1,gpt1` not found.
```

I have tried the solution listed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182453/after-installing-ubuntu-windows-became-unbootable-but-files-are-still-there) like updating grub, moving grub to a different disk, reinstalling grub, etc. But none of them worked.

The weird thing is that if I boot into Windows using the boot menu (F9) windows boots fine, and if I reboot from windows into the grub, the Windows option boot windows correctly. It's only after booting into Manjaro and then Windows that I get the error.

EDIT:

`lsblk` output

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   3,3M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/exercism/5
loop1         7:1    0  30,9M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/9607
loop2         7:2    0 126,8M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/signal-desktop/331
loop3         7:3    0  97,7M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/10185
loop4         7:4    0 163,7M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/spotify/41
loop5         7:5    0  55,3M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1885
loop6         7:6    0  30,9M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/9721
loop7         7:7    0 161,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop8         7:8    0  62,1M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop9         7:9    0 162,9M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop10        7:10   0  55,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1932
loop11        7:11   0 126,9M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/signal-desktop/333
loop12        7:12   0 169,3M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/spotify/42
loop13        7:13   0  97,7M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/10126
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931,5G  0 part 
sdb           8:16   0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0   260M  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb3        8:19   0 223,3G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 101,9G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    17G  0 part [SWAP]
```

`grub.cfg` windows entry:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-9287-5622' {
        savedefault
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        set root='hd1,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,gpt1' --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  9287-5622
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9287-5622
        fi
        chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

Comment: You could try finding the right disk from the GRUB shell (press `c` in GRUB menu, then run `insmod part_gpt` and `insmod ntfs` and try to locate the partiton with [`ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#ls)). Could you add the output of `lsblk` and the windows entry of your `grub.cfg`?

Comment: In the grub if I edit the windows entry and change `set root='hd1,gpt1'` to `set root='hd0,gpt1'` I get a new error `error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.`

Comment: After re-reading your question: are you loading grub as an EFI loader every time? Windows may not boot if it's not. I would expect a different error, but if you say it works sometimes (after booting into windows), it could be the reason too. You'd have to make sure to select `GRUB (UEFI)` or similar as the boot option.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows, or Windows that is not hibernated. And Windows fast startup sets hibernation flag. Windows also turns fast start up back on with updates. So check fast start up settings. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Windows fast startup is already disabled. I just checked.

Comment: @rudib How do I select GRUB (UEFI) as the boot option?

Comment: @Zoford you should be able to do so in the BIOS/Boot menu if it's set up correctly. You should be able to set it as default too. To be honest, I've never used grub with uefi, I switched to refind.

Comment: In my BIOS under UEFI Boot Order and OS Boot Manager I have 3 options. Manjaro, Windows Boot Manager and UEFI OS which is on the same disk as manjaro. I tried switch the order around and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Not sure what to make of that. But you can verify the boot mode by checking if `/sys/firmware/efi` exists. The Manjaro entry sounds like EFI as with BIOS boot the entry should't have a custom name. So that seems fine. You might be experiencing the same issue I had (because of which I switched to refind). If I recall correctly, GRUB has no way of handling multiple EFI partitions. I think it'll always default to the one it's started from. But as the Windows loader is on another disk, it can't find it. If I'm right, your options are either

Comment: unifying your EFI partitions (windows and linux on one partition) or using a bootloader that can handle multiple EFI partitions (like [refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)).

Comment: **Correction:** I don't think that it was GRUB that can't handle multiple EFI partitions, it was `systemd-boot`. It might still be a related issue.

Comment: Could you also run `blkid`? I'd like to make sure that it actually matches up.

Comment: I installed refind and it works great! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad it works! The dynamic auto-detection at boot time works wonders.

Comment: @rudib could you please write the answer?

Comment: @Andra here you go. Unfortunately not a solution for the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Speculation:** Using multiple EFI Partitions is a non-standard approach and can lead to some issues. AFAIK, GRUB should still be able to work with that - however I couldn't find the issue here and I don't have a working setup for reference.

**Alternative solution without GRUB**

[rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is a *boot manager* that I can confirm to be able to handle multiple EFI partitions. Because of dynamic auto-detection at boot time, almost no configuration is required.